# How can I update the text of a TextView if the TextView is in an included activity?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a ViewFlipper in my **main_activity** and there are included activities (pages).

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/vf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_news"
        layout="@layout/activity_news"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_latest_posts"
        layout="@layout/activity_latest_posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_categories"
        layout="@layout/activity_categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    ...
</ViewFlipper>
```

[The acitvities (pages) have their own java files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWt2e.png)
I tried to modify a textView from there:

```
public class latest_posts extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View myView = findViewById(R.id.include_latest_posts);

        TextView tv = myView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        tv.setText("HELLO");
    }
}
```

But when I ran the app, nothing happened. How can I access the Views from the java file of page-acitvity?

I also tried to create an onClick function for a Button in an included activity. It worked in the MainActivity's java file where the VievFlipper is. How can I create an onClick function in the included activity's java file?

Comment: lets make variable   View myview = findViewById(R.id,include_latest_posts);

then Try to find Your TextView  
TextView text = myview.FindViewById(R.id.textId);

and then Change text

Comment: Thank you! It worked just when I used it in activity_main.java. But what can I do if I want to use latest_posts.java?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    private TextView _textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_latest_posts);
        _textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTv);
        _textView.setText("It works!");
    }
```